# Problemas para compartir el mismo eje x y y

Tags: python

Hola tengo problemas para crear un plot, como muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el plot de arriba comparte el eje x con el de plot de abajo, y el plot de la izquierda comparte el eje y con el plot de la derecha. En el plot de la derecha también se puede observar un buscador de picos.
¿Que le podria agregar para obtner el mismo resultado?

El código es el siguiente (de una pregunta anterior):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(100, 350).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
data -= data.min()
data *= 100 / data.max()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 
0.05})

ax1.plot(data.mean(axis=0))
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', direction='in')
ax2.imshow(data, cmap='inferno', origin='lower', aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

El cual produce la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Las preguntas que buscan opiniones o recomendaciones de librerías, herramientas y demás, suelen terminar cerradas. Además, el título menciona problemas con matplotlib y no vemos ninguno :)

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de @Alfabravo debes subir el código con lo que has intentado, y ver los errores que tienes para que te podamos ayudar. Por guiarte te diré, que sí, se pueden hacer gráficas del estilo que quieres con Matplotlib.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: Ya esta editada